# What is the easiest way to determine if a Maven dependence is actually used?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a few dependencies in a Maven pom I am trimming.  To check them I comment the dependency out and re-run the build.  If it failed, then the dependency is needed.  If it did not fail, then I remove it.

Is there an easier, faster way to check if a dependency is required for a Maven build?

Comment: That's a risky way to determine if something is needed or not, unless your tests exercise every possible path through the system.

Comment: Have you tried the analyze or analyze-only goals of the dependency plugin? See [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html)

Comment: It is risky and I don't like it.  Then again, how do you avoid a build up of legacy dependencies?

Comment: I tested "mvn dependency:analyze" & "mvn dependency:analyze-only".  It stated that my dependencies on "org.slf4j" were "Unused declared".  I commented them out and performed a clean build, which broke my tests.  It does not feel much better than what I was doing before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No solution will be perfect due to the dynamic nature of the java classloader.

A dependency analysis tool like [JarAnalyzer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer) will certainly help identify static or compile-time relationships between jars in a directory.

Dynamic or run-time relationships are much harder to determine, which is why one of the suggestions was to ensure you have a conmprehensive set of units tests that exercises as much of your code as possible.